# Dynamically search with interrupts,via Tasks C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, search-engine, xamarin.forms

I'm working with Db(via **SQLite.NET PCL**,not async version). At current moment i have a *listview* with some data(taken from db),also i got a searchbar/entry(its nvm),where user can input some values and then,via **LINQ** i'm going to make a query and update ***SourceItems*** of my List.

So the problems comes with performance,because my **DB** got million records and simple **LINQ** query working very slow.In other words,when user enter too fast some data,application gets huge lags and sometimes can **Crash**.
To resolve this problem,some things come in my mind(theoretically solution):

1)Need to put method(which i make query into db) on Task(to unlock my main UI thread)

2)Initialize timer,then turn on and :

- **if 1 second passed**,then => run my method(query) on Task(similiar to background thread)
- **if 1 second doesn't passed**,then exit from anonymous method.

Something like that(similar) or any suggestions.Thanks!

**UPD:**
So to be honest,i tried too much and didnt get a good result
*BTW*,my current code(Snippets) :
1) My SearchMethod

```
public void QueryToDB(string filter)
        {
            this.BeginRefresh ();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (filter))
            {
                this.ItemsSource = SourceData.Select(x => x.name); // Source data is my default List of items
            }
            else 
            {
                var t = App.DB_Instance.FilterWords<Words>(filter); //FilterWords it's a method,where i make direct requests to the database 
                this.ItemsSource = t.Select(x => x.name); 
            }
            this.EndRefresh ();
        }
```

2)Searchbar.TextChanged (anonymous method)

```
searchBar.TextChanged +=async (sender, e) => 
                {
                    ViewModel.isBusy = true;  //also i got a indicator,to show progress,while query working
                    await Task.Run(()=> //my background,works fine
                    {
                        listview.QueryToDB(searchBar.Text);
                    });
                    ViewModel.isBusy = false; // after method is finished,indicator turn off

                };
```

The main problem is how to implement this part(with these case's),where 1 second passed and only then i'm going to make query to update my ***sourceItems*** of list(everytime,when user inputs some value into searchbar,this trigger(timer) must refresh again to zero).

Any help will be appreciated,thanks!
PS Sorry for my eng. skills!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do it is to combine `async Task.Run` and `CancellationTokenSource`:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

searchView.TextChanged += async (sender, e) => 
{
    if (cancellationTokenSource != null) cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    var searchBar = (sender as SearchBar);
    if (searchBar != null)
    {
        string searchText = searchBar.Text;
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(650, cancellationToken);

            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) return;

            var searchResults = await Task.Run(() => 
            {
                return ViewModel.Search(searchText);
            });

            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) return;

            ViewModel.YouItems.Repopulate(searchResults);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Expected
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks!! Excatly what i need,works fine.
PS But when introduce first time (some value into searchbar),i get a Exception(for ex. : runing on android device - debug shows "AndroidRunTimeThrowException"),but then works fine,strange glitch!

Comment: No problem. I use it on Android apps and don't get any Exceptions. Make sure CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource; is on top level of the class.

Comment: yes,its global variable ! Strange...very strange :). Tomorrow ill check again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to **wait** before actually performing your search. Killing a search task in midway can cause undefined behavior.

You want to save the current search filter and compared it again 1 second later. If that hasn't changed, do the search. Otherwise, abort :

```
searchBar.TextChanged += async (sender, e) => 
{
    var filter = searchBar.Text;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (filter == searchBar.Text)
            listview.QueryToDB(searchBar.Text);
    });
};
```

As to keep the view model updated, move your `isBusy` assignments inside `QueryToDB` because that is when your view model is truly busy :

```
public void QueryToDB(string filter)
{
    this.BeginRefresh ();
    ViewModel.isBusy = true;

    // do your search

    ViewModel.isBusy = false;
    this.EndRefresh ();
}
```

Comment: Thread.Sleep - i think this is for UI thread,no? Thanks for advice!